# LWC: How to make DIV fit with mobile view

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, css, html

I have two DIVs which I want to fit in Mobile view according to resizing. In the image, you can its behaving like 2nd image and i want it to behave like 3rd image. I am least aware of responsive pages in LWC but here's what I have tried and its not working. Please help --

[image]

```
<lightning-card>
   <lightning-layout multiple-rows>
    <lightning-layout-item size="12" padding="around-small">
      **DIV1**  //My entire DIV block 1 here
     </lightning-layout-item>
     <lightning-layout-item size="12" padding="around-small">
       **DIV2** //My entire DIV block 2 here
    </lightning-layout-item>
  </lightning-layout>
</lightning-card>
```

Answer (score 3):

from the docs - [Create Responsive Layouts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.mobile_layout)

you can use the *-device-size property to change the size depending on the viewport.

Example:

```
    <lightning-card>
  <lightning-layout multiple-rows>
     <lightning-layout-item size="12" 
          small-device-size="9"
          padding="around-small">
          <p>Main Content Goes Here</p>
      </lightning-layout-item>
      <lightning-layout-item size="12"
          small-device-size="3"
          padding="around-small">
          <p>Sidebar Content Goes Here</p>
      </lightning-layout-item>
  </lightning-layout>
</lightning-card>
```

Comment: Hi Glls, I tried this but somehow all messed up. :(

Answer (score 1):

I will add important details for the answer provided by @glls. Documentation for [layout-item](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-layout-item/documentation)

> If you specify the small-device-size, medium-device-size, or
> large-device-size attributes, you must also specify the size
> attribute.
>
> If you specify the size and small-device-size attributes, the size
> attribute applies to small mobile phones, and the small-device-size
> applies to smart phones. The device sizing attributes are additive and
> apply to devices of the specified size and larger. For example, if you
> set medium-device-size=10 and don't set large-device-size, then the
> medium-device-size setting applies to tablets, desktops, and larger
> devices. You'd also have to set size to apply to devices smaller than
> tablets.

That being said, if you sepcify `small-device-size` `size` should have the same value.

```
<lightning-card>
    <lightning-layout multiple-rows>
        <lightning-layout-item size="12" small-device-size="12" medium-device-size="6" padding="around-small">
            **DIV1**  //My entire DIV block 1 here
        </lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-layout-item size="12" small-device-size="12" medium-device-size="6" padding="around-small">
            **DIV2** //My entire DIV block 2 here
        </lightning-layout-item>
    </lightning-layout>
</lightning-card>
```

---

The layout system is mobile-first. Typically, the `small-device-size` attribute indicates a smart phone, `medium-device-size` indicates a tablet, and `large-device-size` indicates a desktop or larger device.